# Subquery with Select statement works in 12C but not on 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, subquery

```
Select 
  c.id AS case_id, 
  c.id AS case_number, 
  tt.description as Target_Type, 
  coalesce(
    v_vendors.vendor_number, 
    vma.org_code, 
    TO_CHAR(sm.staff_member_id), 
    la.org_code, 
    oe.other_fns_number, 
    TO_CHAR(oe.other_id), 
    TO_CHAR(c_clients.client_id)
  ) as Target_Identifier, 
  coalesce(
    v_vendors.vendor_name, 
    vma.name, 
    s_wic_users.username, 
    la.name, 
    oe.other_name, 
    UPPER(
      c_clients.last_name || ', ' || c_clients.first_name
    )
  ) as Target_Name, 
  c.date_opened AS Open_Date, 
  c.date_closed AS Close_Date, 
  t.target_type_id, 
  t.target_id, 
  s.description AS Status, 
  case when aIosm.last_name is null then '' else UPPER(
    aIosm.last_name || ', ' || aIosm.first_name
  ) end Investigator, 
  case when aSosm.last_name is null then '' else UPPER(
    aSosm.last_name || ', ' || aSosm.first_name
  ) end Supervisor, 
  c.Notes AS Supervisor_Comments, 
  aI.Date_Assigned as Assign_Date, 
  ----subquery starts
  (
    select 
      lat.description 
    from 
      investigation_actions_taken iat 
      join investig_lu_action_type lat on iat.action_type_id = lat.id 
    where 
      iat.investigation_case_id = c.id 
      and iat.is_deleted <> 'T' 
    order by 
      iat.date_assessed desc, 
      iat.date_created desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  ) AS Last_Action 
from 
  v_investigation_cases c 
  join investigation_target t on c.target_id = t.target_id 
  join v_lu_inv_status s on (
    case when date_closed <= TRUNC(sysdate) then 2 else case when date_opened > TRUNC(sysdate) then 2 else 1 end end
  ) = s.status_id 
  join investigation_target_type tt on t.target_type_id = tt.target_type_id
  ---left join starts  
  left join investigation_case_assignment aI on c.id = aI.investigation_case_id 
  and aI.date_roll_off is null 
  and aI.assignment_type = 'I' 
  left join o_staff_members aIosm on aI.staff_member_id = aIosm.staff_member_id 
  left join investigation_case_assignment Super on c.id = Super.investigation_case_id 
  and Super.date_roll_off is null 
  and Super.assignment_type = 'S' 
  left join o_staff_members aSosm on Super.staff_member_id = aSosm.staff_member_id 
  -----left join starts  
  left join v_vendors on t.vendor_id = v_vendors.id 
  left join o_organizational_units vma on t.vendor_management_area_id = vma.seq_id 
  left join c_clients on t.client_id = c_clients.client_id 
  left join o_staff_members sm on t.user_id = sm.staff_member_id 
  left join s_wic_users on sm.staff_member_id = s_wic_users.sm_staff_member_id 
  left join investigation_other_entity oe on t.non_wic_vendor_id = oe.other_id 
  left join o_organizational_units la on t.local_agency_id = la.seq_id 
  ---end of the query
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? We cannot help you with a query alone. And please, format your query by using the Code sample button in the RTE.

Comment: Hi Philippe I am unable to edit the query

Comment: I had a select query with subqueries and joins which was executed fine in 12C but not in 11g

Comment: I edited your question so it's now more readable. Could you paste what error message you get when trying to execute the query in 11g?

Comment: But which i posted the select query is wrong because i am unable to post my select query. getting this error while executing in the 11.2.0.3           Error at line 12
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Hi Philippe, Can you please help me on that above error

Comment: You are dividing by zero, but with value 1 instead of 0 this query runs fine on [Oracle 11.2.0.2](http://rextester.com/RVJ13322).

Comment: Above query is not i am using

Comment: Please find the above query and iam getting the error as Error at line 12
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: `ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY ` is only valid in 12c not in 11g.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik..Is there any way to solve the query

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article about what you can achieve in Oracle 12c with the OFFEST FETCH based on Kaushik Nayak.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_offset_fet_first_rows_only.htm

I hope it can help you to convert your original query to 11g. Good luck.